# WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I wrote this:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service


driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:\01_Jan\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.caseking.de/asus-geforce-rtx-3070-ekwb-8g-8192-mb-gddr6-gcas-430.html?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=3cc7dd10a046b37a91fb7442f67d7ae567894c63-1617776732-0-AXx4q2kIFylIaJSzZgO0fhK5spbXk1-Z576z2JLy3LVMU1OsY0QI8qDP0wdoL4ZAU8TFMMKqEm_H6ZkIIXBasbtpmT29tQr5WBaWo40n9jUiUpzTbmSfisq061bqribf1AuvWlXzx77xKhIX0UMPPnfznvKbQ-fGGM9H6OxX2GeHRkrsbWeIgW9Q-4Z5DgX-5GqqStAbcZP-JlkXsXS9b9AZ2HAKLGiqyiir3pFwfyP-OImwuvG9jrbmDwTQADEe8zuWMzTuKNCYyPQnGC7BmXxjrV5hMnzD5ly15IaXw_s81qlTzafaSO3Mst258F5VnHSkCNwN32frijhm-jyguObin6vIVdFsKnITJzmmxvW9vkrI6zlGPtGyZyOgxOV_GD5XNlw8Pe2OqmoQsY9uiPfozWjSzyJZLw4AIUeQPetxTQNFUKNbcmFYQJvoSuFc21j82l5cYQyGGWNPSzcPOa4JDvCSe8Eco3H1AhPt30XGx_965Njhq9mYsIDfUqDpk13FEmotoMnFZdK5F5rW_W0')
```

And I am getting the following Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\atrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start
self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
File "C:\Users\atrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in **init**
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "C:\Users\atrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Bot.py", line 8, in 
driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:\01_Jan\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
File "C:\Users\atrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in **init**
self.service.start()
File "C:\Users\atrei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Thanks for help

Comment: ```driver = webdriver.Chrome(excecutable_path="D:\01_Jan\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")```

Comment: Now, there is the following Error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Bot.py", line 8, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(excecutable_path="D:\01_Jan\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'excecutable_path'`

Answer (score 1):

Try using webdriver-manager:

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

what I prefer mostly and use it like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

it will install driver and store automatically in suited path

Answer (score -1):

in my case i copy the chromedriver my jupyter path(in my case c:/users/erkin) and its worked